# How to specify covariates in maSigPro analysis (like limma)

Tags: r, bioconductor

Is it possible to adjust the model in the time course analysis with Bioconductor package maSigPro? Similar to how covariates can be used in limma model.

Comment: Your question may get more attention on the Bioconductor support site: https://support.bioconductor.org/.

Comment: Or https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/